# Dynamic content via PHP cookie and caching limitations

Tags: php, caching, cookies

I have coded some consent functionality in PHP.

I display a consent notice with an accept button, if the consent cookie is not set then it displays the notice, if the user clicks the accept button it sets the consent cookie.

If the user has not accepted some functionality like contact forms and a reCAPTCHA script are not included in the page. If they have accepted it includes them.

My host uses a caching platform, when a page is visited for the first time it caches the contents of the page, if another user then visits that page it serves it from the cache.

The issue I have is that if I purge that cache then visit a page for the first time (with no cookie set) then it displays the message, but this gets cached. Then if another user who does have the accepted cookie they are still being served the cached page as if they have not accepted.

This is also the same the other way around, if first person to access the page has a cookie set, then other users who then access that page without the cookie set they see the page as if the cookie is set.

If I wish to keep this PHP functionality is there any way to do this without disabling the cache entirely?

I have looked into sending no-cache headers if the cookie is set, but that would just mean that the unaccepted version of the page is served up, and if a user has the cookie then they are going to still see the unaccepted version of the page not the accepted.

Comment: If the page content differs per visitor, and the page is generated on the server per visitor, then you simply cannot cache it. Which is of course not very good for scalability. Which is why this optional stuff is usually added to the page via Javascript. Also, omitting a CAPTCHA when the user didn't accept cookies very much defeats the point of a CAPTCHA.

Comment: Your hoster's caching mechanism would need to be configured to take cookie values into account then. (Whether that is possible with the system you are using, you'd have to ask them.) The alternative would be to use client-side JavaScript to show/hide the notice, based on whether that JS finds that cookie, or not.

Comment: @deceze they did mention contact forms in the same sentence as the CAPTCHA there, so I would assume that means when no consent is given, _both_ will not be present.

Comment: Sorry, I've just reworded it, if accept is given the contact forms and reCAPTCHA script (which transfers data to Google) is available, without they are not. The JS method is okay for showing/hiding the notice, but the concern is with having to enqueue the reCAPTCHA JS after the page has loaded

Comment: Configure cache control headers : if (!isset($_COOKIE['consent'])) {
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
}

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I have considered this, but do not see how it could work as if you set no-cache if the cookie is not there then the cached version is going to be the cookie accepted version, so anyone new to the site will see the accepted version from the cache? It doesn't seem possible to set a no-cache header because the cached version needs to be cookie aware

Comment: you can modify the cache control headers to differentiate between new visitors and returning visitors who have already provided consent.to achieve this is by using conditional headers based on the presence of the consent cookie.if (!isset($_COOKIE['consent'])) {
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
} else {
  header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600");
} and you can utilize the Vary header in combination with the cache control headers

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work, that code looks like if the cookie is not set then dont cache the page, if it is set then cache it - but that means the accepted version of the page gets cached, and therefore users who have not accepted get the accepted version...?

Comment: You can instruct a cache to _vary_ the behaviour based on different headers with the `Vary` HTTP header. You should simply always set your cache headers to the desired cache allowance *and add a `Vary` header*. Then a cookie-less request should be caching the unaccepted version, and every other unique cookie should lead to its own cached version. Of course, that largely removes the point of any cache to begin with, so just always disabling the cache would appear to make the most sense. To what degree your host's cache honours all this we don't know.